# How to display the quantity of items

Tags: javascript

The page from the database in the loop outputs elements:
Dish №1, Dish №2, Dish №1, Dish №3, Dish №3

How to display their total quantity:
Dish №1 - 2 items, Dish №2 - 1 items, Dish №3 - 2 items

```js
let order = document.querySelectorAll('.order');

order.forEach(element => {
    arr = element.textContent
    console.log(arr)
});
```

```html
<span class="order">Dish №1</span>
<span class="order">Dish №2</span>
<span class="order">Dish №1</span>
<span class="order">Dish №3</span>
<span class="order">Dish №3</span>
```

So far I have only been able to display all the items in the console, but I can't get the quantity of each item

Comment: Pretty sure there are a bunch of different approaches to this, but could you not just do something like create a count variable for each dish and string match the text itself, incrementing each count as needed?

Answer (score 0):

There's couple of ways to get to the result you want, this is one of them:

```js
let order = ['1','1','2','3','3'];
    let map = new Map();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if (map.get(order[i]) === 1) {
            map.set(order[i], map.get(order[i]) + 1)
        } else {
            map.set(order[i], 1)
        }
    }

console.log(map)
```

So, your entries will be on `map.keys()` and the quantity on `map.values()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
let order = document.querySelectorAll(".order");
let orderObj = {};
order.forEach((element) => {
  if (orderObj[element.textContent] === undefined) {
    orderObj[element.textContent] = 0;
    orderObj[element.textContent]++;
  } else {
    orderObj[element.textContent]++;
  }
});
Object.keys(orderObj).map((e) => {
  console.log(e + " - " + orderObj[e] + " items");
});
```

```html
<span class="order">Dish №1</span>
<span class="order">Dish №2</span>
<span class="order">Dish №1</span>
<span class="order">Dish №3</span>
<span class="order">Dish №3</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ A 'good answer' also includes a sentence or two in plain text that explains why you think your solution will work. Please visit SO Help Center and specifically this guideline for more details >>> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @inputforcolor thanks for your advice and guide